# Is there a way to handle any type of collection, instead of solely relying on Array, List, etc?

Tags: c#, performance, collections

This example is for a method called "WriteLines", which takes an array of strings and adds them to an asynchronous file writer. It works, but I am curious if there is an interesting way to support -any- collection of strings, rather than relying on the programmer to convert to an array.

I came up with something like:

```
public void AddLines(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    // grab the queue
    lock (_queue)
    {
        // loop through the collection and enqueue each line
        for (int i = 0, count = lines.Count(); i < count; i++)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(lines.ElementAt(i));
        }
    }
    // notify the thread it has work to do.
    _hasNewItems.Set();
}
```

This appears to work but I have no idea of any performance implications it has, or any logic implications either (What happens to the order? I assume this will allow even unordered collections to work, e.g. `HashSet`).

Is there a more accepted way to achieve this?

Comment: You can send it anything that *is* an `IEnumerable<string>` (i.e. `List<string>`).  An IEnumerable doesn't guarantee order, so if that's important, you should consider if IEnumerable suits your needs

Comment: Don't ever use more than a LINQ method on a `IEnumerable<>` or enumerate it more than once, unless you have strong guarantees on how it has been generated. Some `IEnumerable<>` are rebuilt each time you look at them... For example if you passed `File.ReadLines()` as a parameter, the file would be re-read once for the `lines.Count()` and once for each `ElementAt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've been passed an `IEnumerable<string>` - that means you can iterate over it. Heck, there's even a language feature *specifically* for it - `foreach`:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    _queue.Enqueue(line);
}
```

Unlike your existing approach, this will only iterate over the sequence once. Your current code will behave differently based on the underlying implementation - in some cases `Count()` and `ElementAt` are optimized, but in some cases they aren't. You can see this really easily if you use an iterator block and log:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetItems()
{
    Console.WriteLine("yielding a");
    yield return "a";
    Console.WriteLine("yielding b");
    yield return "b";
    Console.WriteLine("yielding c");
    yield return "c";
}
```

Try calling `AddLines(GetItems())` with your current implementation, and look at the console...

Comment: Honestly I was avoiding `foreach` as this code is used in Unity, which is running an old version of Mono that has various GC unboxing/boxing issues with `foreach`. Though thinking about it now, I don't actually think it would apply to strings. And your example is very interesting, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @mGuv: How do you think `Count()` is going to work *more* efficiently than `foreach`?

Comment: By being naive and assuming Count() would just return some internal member variable that was being used to store the current length, similar to how arrays do it :P

Comment: @mGuv: Be aware that `Count()` is just an extension method. It doesn't have access to any extra members of `IEnumerable<T>`. Basically the *only* thing you can do with an `IEnumerable<T>` is call `GetEnumerator()` on it, and then work with the result... and that's exactly what `foreach` does.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So I should stick to `foreach`? To be honest, I wrote that piece of code without searching anything and just using intellisense to show me what `IEnumerable` had publicly available.

Comment: @mGuv There is no boxing possible on a `string`, it is a reference type.

Comment: @xanatos: Indeed. This code *will* box if you pass it a `List<string>`, because the underlying iterator would be a `List<string>.Enumerator` - but that's going to be the case whatever you do.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer as well since you are using threads, use a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, like so:

```
// the provider method
// _queue = new BlockingCollection<string>()
public void AddLines(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
   foreach (var line in lines)
   {
     _queue.Add(line);
   }
}
```

No locks required, and allows for multiple consumers and providers since we flag for each element added.

The consumer basically only has to do `var workitem = _queue.Take();`

Comment: What's the point of using a semaphore (or other synchronization) when you're using a `ConcurrentQueue`?

Comment: @Johnbot So the consuming thread can be put to sleep? Instead of an active `while(!_queue.TryDequeue(out res))` loop?

Comment: Ofcourse, I was thinking of [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) which [by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287116(v=vs.110).aspx) acts as a queue. There Take is blocking so you don't have to roll your own external synchronization.